# Использование str.replace (либо другого способа) для замены отдельных значений в DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, replace

Каким образом заменить в обрабатываемом массиве данных пробельный символ?

Имею большой массив данных (больше 500 тыс строк) в .txt.
Читаю массив:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding=ENCODING, sep='\t',decimal=',')
```

Ловлю предупреждение:

```
DtypeWarning: Columns (7,13) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
```

Итоговый DataFrame состоит из:

```
calculation                 object
period              datetime64[ns]
status                      object
baket                       object
remainder                    int64
nil                        float64
pdz                        float64
ead                         object
recovery                   float64
lgd                        float64
pd_month                   float64
rezervation_rate           float64
pd_lgd_ead                 float64
reserve                     object
```

Нахожу вхождения в столбце `ead`, в которых содержится пробельный символ:

```
non_numeric = df.ead.str.contains('\s', na=False)
df.loc[non_numeric].ead.size # 1
```

Проблема в том, чтобы заменить эти вхождения на нечто, позволяющее в итоге конвертировать в числовой тип.

Метод `df.ead.str.replace('\s', '')` возвращает копию df.ead, удаляя пробельный символ, но при этом все остальные значения устанавливаются в NaN (что, в общем-то понятно).
Метод `df.loc[non_numeric].ead.str.replace('\s', '')` возвращает одну строку с нужным значением. Не могу придумать как одну строку исходного массива заменить на полученный результат.

Прямой способ не срабатывает:

```
df.loc[non_numeric].ead = df.copy().loc[non_numeric].ead.str.replace('\s', '')
non_numeric = df.ead.str.contains('\s', na=False)
df.loc[non_numeric].ead.size # 1
```

В итоге вопрос: как заменить одно значение ячейки массива данных на другое?

Comment: Буду признателен за подсказку как обрабатывать такой случай еще на этапе открытия файла: если добавляю атрибут  thousands="\xa0", это приводит к тому, что в других колонках, где используется простой пробел "\x20", не распознаются числовые значения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

можно попробовать так:

```
cols = ['ead', 'reserve']
df[cols] = df[cols].replace(r'\D', '', regex=True).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Answer (score 1):

В итоге решением является:

```
df.ead.replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'\D',value=r'')
df.ead = df.ead.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Для полноты картины, второй столбец так же обрабатываю:

```
df.reserve.replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'\D',value=r'')
df.reserve = df.reserve.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

В итоге добился желаемого:

```
calculation                 object
period              datetime64[ns]
status                      object
baket                       object
remainder                    int64
nil                        float64
pdz                        float64
ead                        float64
recovery                   float64
lgd                        float64
pd_month                   float64
rezervation_rate           float64
pd_lgd_ead                 float64
reserve                    float64
```